# is there any way to make an add-on password protected?

Tags: add-on

This is for studio use where only a few people are given passwords which will  show the add-on content. Is it possible to password protect an add-on?

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. What is the reasoning behind making it password protected? If it is just to limit distribution then you could just share it in a passworded zip and users would need to extract it before adding it to blender. If you want some other form of control you'll need to explain in a fair bit more detail exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: so the studio content dont go out of the studio, is there any way ? because once we install blender and addons in the computers . then anyone can copypaste anything , is there anyway so we can add limitation inside of an addon where user can first have to login , or something like that, 

I think blender id addon has that thing , m i right ?

Comment: addons are just files/folders, usually, and permissions can be set on them, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not 100% possible (edit: if the addon is meant to work offline), but it is possible to make it hard to hack the addon.

The addon is written in python, which is byte-code-compiled interpreted language. Anyone with access to the addon will have access to it's source and will be able to reverse-engineer what password that addon needs easily.

You can make this harder by:

1. [Obfuscating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/obfuscating-python-code) the source-code - this will just make it human non-readable.
2. Use a exe-packager like py2exe. But the layout of the executable is well-known and the Python byte-codes are well understood so it is possible to easily hack it.
3. Use a C extension called from Python which will have all the necessary components that the addon can't funtion without. The Python will then only use and display those results inside Blender UI. This way the license check code can be hard to break (but not impossible) and hard to reverse engineer.

Answer (score 2):

Jerryno's answer is technically correct. But there is a potential solution if you really really want to try this.

For what you describe, you could possibly host the addon code on a separate server that requires authentication, and then have a simple addon that loads the rest of the addon from this server each time it is run. This would probably be very tricky to get right though.

I would question whether you actually need this level of protection? Copyright protection should be enough in many countries. Other assets from the studio (e.g. models) can easily be removed, they are only protected by copyright. What damage to the studio's business/bottom line will this actually cause (I suspect most studios do not worry about this at all).

Comment: as a studio business i dont think this will effect a lot , you are right ,but its is just a thought , about if its possible or not , but thanks for the help guys

Comment: You are right, I should add to my answer it was targeted towards offline usage. Cloud based or server hosted solution will definitely work, but it will cost money and time for it to perform well. Some addons operate on datasets with size in GB. That would be hard to send over network.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily thinking of the server to do the work, rather dynamically load code received from the server. Either way though, a lot of work for something that probably isn't a big deal.